OpenAPI Description for Spring Boot 3 (jakarta.ws.rs) project

I have created a spring boot project (spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.4.0) using the IntelliJ IDEA wizard with spring-boot-starter-jersey.

I have created HelloWorldResource:


@Path("/hello-world")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}


I have created JerseyConfig:

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(HelloWorldResource.class);
    }
}


Now my resource is available at http://localhost:8080/hello-world.

How can I add OpenAPI Description generation capability to my project that uses jakarta.ws.rs annotations (formerly known as JAX-RS)?

The comments suggest using springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui, but it doesn't work for Jersey as the documentation says:

Does springdoc-openapi support Jersey?

If you are using JAX-RS and as implementation Jersey (@Path for example), we do not support it.
We only support exposing Rest Endpoints using Spring managed beans (@RestController for example).



I think you can use springdoc-openapi. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341682/4024340

@DouglasMyers-Turnbull I tried to add the springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui as stated on https://springdoc.org but when calling /swagger-ui.html or /v3/api-docs I got 404.

Default path for swagger-ui with springdoc-openapi is /swagger-ui/index.html, e.g. http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Hello @RoarS. Your URL gives the same response code (404). Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but the documentation says: "add the library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional configuration is needed)".

@RoarS. , I looked at the documentation, it says that they do not support the Jersey. I added this nuance to the question.
